# Do Bootstrap LESS variables stand for SCSS variables as well?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

I use Bootstrap 3.3.6 for my projects.

I used to write custom styles by importing the main bootstrap.less file and then changing Bootstrap LESS variales listed here:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables.

It worked OK.

Now I want to try the SASS version of Bootstrap.

I've set up the environment, replaced the original Bootstrap LESS files with SCSS files and compiled the stylesheets. It looked good so far. Then I tried to change some of the variables, e.g.:

```
$navbar-height: 60px;
$navbar-default-bg: #333333;
```

Taken they have the same names as in the LESS version. It compiled with no errors, however the new styles didn't have any effect.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For those who might be looking for an answer, turned out that we need to import the original Bootstrap files in the very end of the file (after the custom values) for them to take effect. This seems to be caused by original value to be set as !default with sass.

```
// Import custom styles

@import "colors";
@import "navbar";

// Import original styles

@import "../bootstrap/sass/bootstrap";
```

And, yes, Bootstrap LESS values names listed on the official website stand for the SCSS values as well.